# SQL Server 2012 AlwaysOn

Tags: sql-server-2012, alwayson

I am trying to access SQL Server 2012 db always on listener (secondary replica, with `ApplicationIntent=ReadOnly` parameter) with a SQL Server user authentication through untrusted domain and I am getting error:

> This is usually a temporary error during hostname resolution and means that the local server did not receive a response from an authoritative server

Can anyone help me on with this?

Answer (score -1):

It might be a DNS problem. Can you use ip address instead of dns name? Perhaps you should check that DNS server is working? If it works with IP address, the problem is DNS related.

If you use trusted domain, the DNS server is needed to be configured since AD needs dns for functioning properly.